# Missing or insufficient permissions on an open read/write firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm getting an alert saying that I have missing or insufficient permissions when trying to access anything within this collection on the client-side of the app. On the console however, I get am able to do creating and writing. I also made sure to allow my other collections to be open read/write, however that still gives me insufficient permissions. Is there an issue with my formatting?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own. Can you edit your question to show the minimal code with which you get that error message?

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue may be that you have the `if true` clause in there, but with no variable to compare against. if "what" is true? its blank. so the security rules block you from accessing the docs because it cant verify that nothing is true.

if you just want to have a wide open security rule then just use this.

```
allow read, write;
```

and remove the if true statement.